# Anime with strength level written on hand

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking at an anime that i saw a while ago in a shorts but couldn't find it later.
So basically it was a world where people's level of strength (power) was written on hand, there was scene were a guy with 10 level tried to fight a 9 guy and couldn't beat him. After that the second guy reveals that his true level on hand was 90 and everyone got shocked.
Any clues what this could be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about how long ago "a while" was?  Can you describe the appearance of either character, or the scene they appeared in?

Comment: A few years back (2-3 at least). It was some kinda training camp or contest maybe where the scene happened

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReadingsAreOffTheScale has a few cases of "looks like a low number because it's cut off", but nothing quite matches this case.

Comment: If you are logged onto a Youtube account and haven't disabled your watch history, you can find the short among the videos: https://www.youtube.com/feed/history

Comment: The 80's OVA Ai City has characters with power levels on their *foreheads*...

Comment: And in a fight near the beginning, a characters level starts at 5 (making his opponent think he'll be a complete pushover) and starts rapidly increasing all the way to ∞. Different details but same basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's [Plunderer](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37345/Plunderer) but I'm not sure though.
This is a description:

> Alcia is a world governed by "Count": numbers engraved on a person's body, representing any number related to their life. These Counts determine a person's social status and power in Alcia. If a Count reaches zero, the person is sent to the Abyss, a place rumored to be worse than death. Hina, a traveler whose Count is based on the distance she traveled, witnessed her mother get dragged down into the Abyss. Determined to fulfill her mother's last wishes, she sets off on a journey in search of the legendary Aces—heroes of the war that happened three hundred years ago, bearing a white star next to their Count. While wandering around, Hina encounters Licht Bach, a mysterious masked man with negative Count, and Nana, the owner of a tavern. In the midst of having a good time, Hina is tricked into a battle with a military soldier. However, despite his negative count, Licht rescues Hina and reveals that he has another count, one with a white star, one of a legendary Ace. Plunderer follows the journey of Hina and other inhabitants of Alcia as they discover the truth about their world, the Abyss, and the legendary Aces